# Get DataTable row reference for a matching row in PrimeReact

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I am using DataTable component from [prime-react](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/#/datatable) in my React application to create a data table. The table displays rows of data corresponding to some other data displayed besides the table. My requirement is that whenever the user clicks on this other data, the corresponding row in the table (matching that data) should be highlighted. I explored the APIs given for `DataTable`, and I came across `filter` method which might be able to achieve this by giving me a DOM reference to the row which matches the data clicked. But I am not sure how to use the `filter` method. I tried using a `ref` on the `DataTable` like this but it didn't work:

```
import React, { createRef } from "react";

const tableRef = createRef();

<DataTable
   ref={tableRef}
   value={props.value}
/>

tableRef.filter(); // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
const [reference , setReference] = useState();
<DataTable value={props.value} ref={(arg) => setReference(arg)} />
```